# Open set implies the theorem, but does the condition imply the set is open?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Below is the theorem and my proof.

**Theorem :** $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $U,V \subseteq X$ are sets with $U$ open, such that $U \cap V=\varnothing$. Then $U \cap \overline V=\varnothing$ as well.

Proof : Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $U \cap \overline V \ne \varnothing$. Let $x \in U\cap \overline V$. Note that $x \notin U \cap V$ thus $x \in U$ and $x \in V'$ . As $U$ is open, there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq U$. Also, $x \in V'$, hence $B(x, \varepsilon)\cap V \ne \varnothing$. But $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap V \subseteq U\cap V=\varnothing$, contradiction.

It's all good, but I want to ask if whenever $U,V$ are such that $U\cap V=U\cap \overline V =\varnothing$, then $U$ is open? Till now I haven't found a counterexample, but I feel it's false.

Comment: Do you mean the empty set, $\varnothing$ ("\varnothing"), when you use phi, "$\phi$"?

Comment: Yes, I do. Thank you, I didn't know the latex code for that one.

Comment: If $U$ is such that "$U\cap V = \varnothing \implies U \cap \overline{V} = \varnothing$ for all $V$", then $U$ is open (just take $V = X\setminus U$). But if it's just required for one $V$ (about which nothing more than $U \cap \overline{V} = \varnothing$ is specified), it doesn't follow that $U$ must be open.

Comment: I mean for all $V$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U$ is such that $$\forall V \subseteq X: (U \cap V = \emptyset) \to (U \cap \overline{V} = \emptyset)\tag{1}$$ then indeed $U$ is open.

If $U$ were *not* open, $V:=X\setminus U$ is not closed and so $U \cap V = \emptyset$ while $U \cap \overline{V} \neq \emptyset$ as witnessed by any point in the closure of $V$ that is not in $V$ (and hence in $U$), so $(1)$ does not hold for $U$.

Comment: This is true, but it is not the proposition asked in the question (which said nothing about “all $V$”).

Comment: @DavidK It was added in the comments to the question (the 4th).

Comment: That is why such changes are supposed to be edited into the question and not left in comments.

Answer (score 0):

What if $X=\mathbb R$ under the usual metric, $U=\{0\},$ and $V=\{1\}$?

You asked if the following proposition is true:

> Whenever $U,V$ are such that $U\cap V=U\cap \overline V =\varnothing$, then $U$ is open.

That proposition is false.

Comment: I though $\overline V$ meant the closure?

Comment: Also, $U=\{0\}$ is not open...?

Comment: Of course $U$ is not open, that’s what makes this a counterexample to the proposition that the result implies $U$ is open. Also note that the closure of a closed set is the same set again, but I have made $V$ open now (since you did not ask for a counterexample for $V$).

Comment: I noticed there is no mention of whether $V$ is open, so I’m using a singleton set. You should know that if $V=\{1\}$ then $\overline V=V.$

Comment: It has been pointed out that you added a comment that changed the question. This is an answer to the question as written (not including comments) at the present time. Please edit your questions appropriately in the future.